# Does 10BASE-T contain four wire pairs or two-wire pairs and why is it if it's four wire pairs?

Tags: ethernet, cable, utp

As far as I know, 10BASE-T and 100BASE-T (types of UTP) use two pairs of wires, while 1000BASE-T has four pairs of wires.
But when I look up the photo of 10BASE-T on google, it indeed contains four wire pairs which are four different colours like this below.

[image: 10BASE-T]

Is it just that it has four pairs of wires but only two of them are used to connect nodes? or
Is the photo I found wrong?

A website that confused me.
[https://www.carleton.edu/sysnet_docs/wiring_docs/10baseTprocs.html#:~:text=Currently%2C%20most%20campus%20computers%20with,cabling%20will%20contain%204%20pairs](https://www.carleton.edu/sysnet_docs/wiring_docs/10baseTprocs.html#:%7E:text=Currently%2C%20most%20campus%20computers%20with,cabling%20will%20contain%204%20pairs).

Note that I am not criticizing this website.

I am quite new to network technology. Sorry if this question seems fool.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that 10Base-T and 100Base-Tx use two pairs for communication, while 1000Base-T uses all four.

You may be confused because you're conflating different standards for different items.

10Base-T, 100Base-Tx, *etc*., are signaling and electrical standards from [IEEE](http://www.ieee.com) (802.3i).

The cable itself is defined by [ISO/IEC 11801](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_11801), and is called Category 5, 5e, 6, *etc*.

The connectors commonly used on the cables are defined by [ANSI](http://www.ansi.org), and are called [TIA-568A or TIA-568B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI/TIA-568), depending on the pairing.

Comment: Might be noteworthy that 10BASE-T (and the previous StarLAN aka 1BASE5) were designed to use the *pre-existing and already common* twisted-pair installations.